# How to show it is impossible to obtain more than 4 distinct real values for $x$ by solving a system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of equations, $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0,$$$$y^2=4ax.$$
How to show it is impossible to obtain more than 4 distinct real values for $x$ by solving them? If there are 4 distinct real values for $x$, then show that their sum is equal to zero.

I noticed these are two equations of a circle and a parabola. But, i could not find any satisfactory algabraic method. How to do this?

Comment: Eliminate $x$ between the two equations and you'll get an equation in $y$ alone. What degree will it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace $x$ by $\frac{y^2}{4a}$ you get a polynomial in the fourth degree in $y$, so you can't have more than 4 solutions for $y$, which automatically means that you can't have more than 4 solutions for $x$.